# For Apple App Store, can I choose an App name same as the App already on App store?

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect, appstore-approval

I want to give a name to my iOS App on App Store like “**Come in**” (just an example)

I have three questions:

- Suppose an App with this name already exist on App Store. Still, can I give that name to my App?
- Before choosing the name for my App, suppose I could not find App with this name on App Store, how can I be sure that this name is not already exists on App Store?
- Can I give a name with a very minor change compared to the App name already on App Store e.g. “**Come In**” or “**Come in..**”? (Capitalize few letters or add dots at end).

Comment: you cant use the same name of the app ,if u used the same the app store reject your app

Comment: It will throw error at time you try to add it to the itunesconnect. no scope of rejection.

Comment: ya you can not use  like **Come In** or **Come in** u can use like **Come** or **Come in.** or **Come In.** , you need to add some this extra in your app name , inside your app you can use **Come In** or **Come in** does not mean.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not directly about programming or coding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I also faced the same issue in last app, its name is `Dipp`, in app store procedure, we **Can't** use the same name of another app. If u used the same name of the app, store will reject your app. For apple [**Documents of Metadata**](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/)

[image]

But you can use like this extra parameter in your app name like **Come** or **Come in.** or **Come In.** . Inside your app you can use **Come In** or **Come in** without a problem, but appstore submission don't add the same name.

Comment: ya sure , you can manually search on itunes you will get same name of the app in search results

Comment: Point n. 2 is slightly trickier. The app name may be taken already. You should create a new app in itunes connect. Then, if the name is already taken, it won't let you select it. There could be an app with a name registered but not in the store yet... You may do the same: if you create an app, then the name is yours for some months (I should check how many).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, we can give app name with minor changes like "**Come in**" to "**Come in..**" on iTunes connect while creating new app with different bundle id but there can be legal consequences from the company having the original name.